# Unable to save variable of type list that extracted from find_elements of Selenium using pickle in Python

Tags: python, selenium, save, pickle

I would like to store a variable of type `list` using `pickle`.

The variable is an output from the function `find_elements_by_css_selector` of the `Selenium` package.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle


browser.get("https://www.freepik.com/search?dates=any&format=search&page=1&query=Polygonal%20Human&sort=popular")
result = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='showcase__link']")

with open('Temp_Result.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(result, f)

print("EndCode")
```

Using the code above, I got the following error

`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'`

Setup:
**PyCharm**

May I know what cause this type of error.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: As far as I know webelements are not serializable by pickle and there is no trivial solution for your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784762

Comment: Hi @trapli, I had to save the variable result for easy debugging. It is time consuming to run the script all over from the beginning just to get the variable result.  I can perform the debugging process more efficient by loading the saved variable result.Hence, I have to disagree with your statement that my question not trivial. But, I appreciate if you have other workaround to achieve the similar objective

Comment: I did not state that your question is or isn't trivial, I was telling that bypassing that error is not trivial. :) To pickle a webelement, you'd need to write a custom serializer / deserializer (see the linked thread).